# Data partition and IntelliJ IDEA external file sync speed

Tags: inotify, bind-mount, intellij

I recently reconfigured the filesystem on my laptop so I can share my data with a second Linux. The Linux used in this matter is Fedora 28, 64-bit.

My disks are now laid out like so:

`/dev/sda`:

- `/dev/sda1` - efi partition
- `/dev/sda2` - swap
- `/dev/sda3` - data partition mounted via `/etc/fstab` at `/media/data_partition`

`/dev/sdb`:

- `/dev/sdb1` - root partition mounted at /
- `/dev/sdb2` - var partition mounted at /var
- `/dev/sdb3` - home partition mounted at /home

The data partition now contains the contents of `/opt`, everything under `$HOME/Documents` and some miscellaneous stuff. They are on the partition with the some directory names (i.e. `opt/`, `Documents/`)

At boot, after the partition is mounted, I have a `bindfs` mount that mounts `/media/data_partition/opt` to `/opt`, and on login in my `$HOME/.bash_profile`, I `bindfs` mount `/media/data_partition/Documents` to `$HOME/Documents`.

When I boot up IntelliJ IDEA, it shows the following:

[image]

Currently I have open a project "located" at `$HOME/Documents/University/Class/project_repo3`. `$HOME/Documents` is the destination for a bind mount from `/media/data_partition/Documents`.

Also, IntelliJ IDEA's installation is located in `/media/data_partition/opt`. This location is the source for a bind mount to `/opt`

The mount seems to be IntelliJ's problem, but I have no idea what the actual issue is, nor which bind mount is the problem. I found these links:

- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000013130-External-file-changes-sync-may-be-slow
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-192665
- https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/04/native-file-system-watcher-for-linux/

The last link explains their new usage of `inotify` and would seem to explain the problem and the solution, but I'm not 100%. I don't wanna change anything, and regret it later.

The questions:

- Is the solution proposed in the last link safe and correct?
- What is inotify (I read part of the manpage, but would appreciate additional explanation)?
- What are inotify watchers, and inotify instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the popup warns of has never happened. I attempted to increase of `fs.inotify.max_user_watches`, but that did not get ride of the popup. In my case, it effectively means nothing.